# Replace part of a function/variable name with C macros

Tags: c, replace, macros, c-preprocessor

I am writing some code that I will want to use multiple times with slightly different function and variable names. I want to replace part of the function and variable names with a macro. gcc filename.c -E shows that the substitution is not being made. How do I rectify this?

Here is some code from the file, before substitution:

```
#define    _CLASS       Object
#define    POOLLEVEL1   1024
#define    POOLLEVEL2   1024


typedef struct {
    int Self;
    int Prev;
    int Next;
    int In_Use;

//----data----//

//----function pointers----//

} Object;

_CLASS* _CLASS_Pool[POOLLEVEL1] = { 0 };
//Note on POOLLEVEL1, POOLLEVEL2: _CLASS_Pool[] is an array of pointers to arrays of type _CLASS. The number of objects in these arrays is LEVEL2, the maximum number of arrays of type object is LEVEL1; The arrays of type object are allocated when needed.

int _CLASS_Available_Head = -1;
int _CLASS_Available_Tail = -1;
//Start and finish of list of available objects in pool.

// More follows
```

Comment: *"shows that the substitution is not being made"* - And how exactly does the source looks like *before* preprocessing?

Comment: This is what the code looks like before AND after preprocessing. I would like the preprocessor to replace instances of '_CLASS' with 'Object'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preprocessor operates on tokens. And when it comes to identifiers `_CLASS` is one token, while `_CLASS_Pool` is another entirely, since they are different identifiers. The preprocessor is not going to stop in the middle of parsing an identifier to check if part of it is another identifier. No, it will gobble up all of `_CLASS_Pool` before recognizing what the identifier is.

If you ever heard the preprocessor does pure textual substitution, that was a gross over-simplification. It operates on *tokens*, something best to always keep in mind.

So what you need is a mechanism by which the preprocessor accepts `_CLASS` as a token, expands it, and then pastes it to another token. Fortunately for you, those mechanisms already exist. It can be written as follows:

```
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_(a, b)
#define CONCAT_(a, b) a ## b
```

To be used like this:

```
_CLASS* CONCAT(_CLASS, _Pool)[POOLLEVEL1] = { 0 };

int CONCAT(_CLASS, _Available_Head) = -1;

/* and so forth */
```

The first `CONCAT` accepts your arguments, and forwards them to another function like macro. Forwarding them allows for any intermediate expansion, like `_CLASS -> Object`. Tokens that aren't object-like macros remains unchanged. `CONCAT_` then simply applies the in-built token pasting operator. You can examine the result and tweak it further.

---

As an aside, the C standard reserves all identifiers that begin by an underscore, followed by an uppercase letter (`_[A-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*`), to the implementation, for any use. Using them yourself leaves you open for undefined behavior. In general, try to avoid leading underscore in identifiers, unless you know all the rules for reserved identifiers by heart.